# Assembly loading in Visual Studio extension

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, vsix

I'm writing a visual studio extension and I'm completely confused about how and where and when it's loading assemblies. What I have is this:

My Visual Studio extension project (let's call it `MyExtension`) references several assemblies including an assembly called `Foo.dll`.

`MyExtension` contains a class called `FooManager` that will be instantiated in response to a menu item being clicked.

When `FooManager` is instantiated it is passed the output path of a project in the current solution and it creates an AppDomain which should load that assembly, something like this:

```
public FooManager(string assemblyPath)
{
    // The actual ApplicationBase of the current domain will be the one of VS and 
    // not of my plugin
    // We need our new AppDomain to be able to find our assemblies
    // without this even the CreateInstanceAndUnwrap will fail
    var p = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
    var cachePath = Path.Combine(p, "Cache");
    var pluginPath = Path.Combine(p, "Test");
    if (Directory.Exists(cachePath))
    {
        Directory.Delete(cachePath, true);
    }
    if (Directory.Exists(pluginPath))
    {
        Directory.Delete(pluginPath, true);
    }
    Directory.CreateDirectory(cachePath);
    Directory.CreateDirectory(pluginPath);
    var newPath = Path.Combine(pluginPath, Path.GetFileName(assemblyPath));
    File.Copy(assemblyPath, newPath, true);

    var setup = new AppDomainSetup()
    {
        ApplicationBase = p,
        ShadowCopyFiles = "true",
        ShadowCopyDirectories = pluginPath,
        CachePath = cachePath              
    };

    domain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("MyTest_AppDomain", AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Evidence, setup);

    // FooCollection is defined in MyExtension. but has several references
    // to things defined in Foo.dll - it used MEF to load the assembly
    // referenced by pluginPath
    collection = domain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(
        typeof(FooCollection).Assembly.FullName,
        typeof(FooCollection).FullName, 
        false, 
        BindingFlags.Default, 
        null, 
        new object[] { pluginPath }, null, null) as FooCollection;
}
```

Now one property of `FooManager` looks like this (`FooInfo` is defined in 
`Foo.dll`):

```
public IEnumerable<FooInfo> Spiders
{
    get
    {
        return collection.Foos.Select(s => s.Metadata);
    }
 }
```

But when I try to access that I get a `System.ArgumentException` with the message `Object type cannot be converted to target type.` which I know happens if two copies of the same assembly are loaded from different locations, and I think, ultimately, that's what's happening here, but I can't figure out how to get it to load from the same place.

So after struggling with this a lot (and the above is only my latest attempt), I thought maybe I could serialize to `byte[]` and then deserialize again as a way to avoid the problem with types, so I tried something like this:

```
var msgBytes = collection.SerializeFooInfo();
var msg = FooInfo.DeserializeMessage(msgBytes);
```

Where my serialize and deserialize just use a `BinaryFormatter` (the classes are marked as `Serializable`). The serialization seems to work, but on deserialization, when I get to here:

```
public static List<FooInfo> DeserializeMessage(byte[] source)
{
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream(source))
    {
        BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        var msg = formatter.Deserialize(stream);
        return msg as List<FooInfo>;
    }
}
```

`msg` comes back as null. If I try to run it in the debugger using the immediate window, I see that `Deserialize` threw a `FileNotFoundException` with the message:

> Cannot load assembly 'C:\Users\matt.burland\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0Exp\ProjectAssemblies\qesxy6ms01\Foo.dll'

But I don't understand where that path came from. It's not where my extension has been installed, which is `C:\Users\matt.burland\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0Exp\Extensions\MyCompany\FooTools\1.0` and was set as the `ApplicationBase` for my `AppDomain` and contains the file `foo.dll`. So why is it trying to load from the other mystery location? The other location seems to be created dynamically and contains only the `foo.dll` assembly.

I've do something very similar to this in a windows service (and using a lot of the same classes) and it works just fine, so this seems to be something particular to the way Visual Studio extensions. Can anybody shine a light here?

So I thought this might help: http://geekswithblogs.net/onlyutkarsh/archive/2013/06/02/loading-custom-assemblies-in-visual-studio-extensions-again.aspx

But if I try to attach an AssemblyResolve handler in package class as suggested it doesn't get called for anything interesting (which isn't surprising, it's not the domain I'm try to load from), but if I try to attach to the new domain I create then if I try something like this:

```
domain.AssemblyResolve += OnAssemblyResolve;
```

Then it fails because my `FooManager` isn't marked as serializable. So I created a proxy just for binding the `AssemblyResolve`, but the `AssemblyResolve` never fires. So I tried not setting the `ApplicationBase` when creating my domain, thinking that would force it to have to try to resolve, but then I can't create my proxy class in the created domain because it *doesn't know where to load the assembly from!*.

Comment: Look at [fusion logs](https://www.bing.com/search?q=fusion+log)/post them (which is first thing to do on assembly loading failure).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: In the case of the deserialize throwing a `FileNotFoundException`, the `FusionLog` is null. Either way, knowing where it's trying to load from is half the problem, the other half is convincing to load from the same place.